# How to replace lines with carriage return in perl?

Tags: perl

How can I find and replace those two lines within the wall of text below?

```
wall of text
    authorize {
            update request {
            }
wall of text
```

I tried this, but it didn't work. The problem is with the carriage return.

```
perl -p0e  "s/authorize \{\nupdate request \{//" ~/test
```

Comment: Did you try `\r\n`? Also, there is whitespace in front of "update request" that you don't take into account in your regex

Comment: Yes there is lots of white space.  Is there a way to capture that in RegEx without counting them? `\r\n` didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
perl -p0e "s/\s*authorize \{\n\s*update request \{\n\s*\}//o" ~/test
```

Comment: That works very well. I have noticed I missed one closing bracket after `update request {` in my original question. Would you be able to include that in your answer please?

Comment: I think I got it: `perl -p0e "s/\s*authorize \{\n\s*update request \{\n\s*\}//o" ~/test`